# cuando ocupa memoria file get contents?

Tags: php, funciones, archivo

el manual php desde un principio dice que transmite el archivo a una cadena. el fichero abc.txt pesa 1gb pero si específico el inicio y el final con file_get_contents('abc.txt', false, NULL, 0, 36) va a cargar solamente lo especificado 0 a 36 bytes en la memoria o de igual manera primero carga todo en la memoria para después mostrar de 0 a 36?

Comment: Te sale algún error al leer esos bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según el código fuente del intérprete PHP ([GitHub](https://github.com/php/php-src), versión 8.1), la función `file_get_contents` llama a una función nativa, escrita en C, llamada `_php_stream_copy_to_mem` y definida en [`main/streams/streams.c`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/ffdf25a2701474a4caae196a0fd980bc3feebd22/main/streams/streams.c#L1460), la cual crea un `string` del mismo tamaño que el enviado por el quinto parámetro de `file_get_contents`, y lee la misma cantidad de bytes del archivo (o, generalizando, `stream`), almacenándolos en el string creado.

Comment: es igual que el parametro max length bytes de getstream_get_line,  fgets o stream_get_contents ?

Comment: que `stream_get_contents` sí. `stream_get_line` opera de forma diferente, pero el parámetro de longitud sí define un máximo de bytes leídos.